# pgfplot: adjust legend style and add several paths

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I read the `pgfplots` manual the whole day, but unfortunately I am not able to achieve the following:

(1) `legend style`: make the legend-equation align left and modify the rectangular box to another shape (or best: remove the box)

(2) adding simple dashed lines, I tried to draw paths, but they don't appear were I want them to :/ e.g. from `x=7` to the intersection of two curves.

```
\documentclass[13pt,a4paper,headlines=6,headinclude=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
      \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xmin=-5,xmax=16,ymin=2,ymax=299,
        extra x ticks={0,4,7},
        tick label style={font=\tiny}, 
        legend style={font=\tiny,legend pos=outer north east}
            ]
            \addplot+[no marks,blue,domain=0.2:10,samples=150, thick] {(x)^3 - 12*(x)^2 + 60*x+98};
        \addlegendentry{$C(x) = x^3 - 12x^2 + 60x+98$};
            \addplot+[no marks,red,domain=0.2:13,samples=150, thick] {3*(x)^2 - 24*x + 60};
            \addlegendentry{$MC(x)=3x^2 - 24x + 60$};
            \addplot+[no marks,orange,domain=0.2:13,samples=150, thick] {(x)^2 - 12*x + 60 + (98)/(x)};
            \addlegendentry{$AV(x)=x^2 - 12x + 60 + \frac{98}{x}$};
            \path[draw=gray, dashed] (4,2) -- (4,50); 
            \path[draw=gray, dashed] (10,-2) -- (10,50); 
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would appreciate any further remarks on how to make this look nicer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For removing the box, use `draw=none` and for aligning equations to the l;eft, use `cells={anchor=west}` in

```
legend style={draw=none,font=\tiny,legend pos=outer north east,cells={anchor=west}}
```

Further, you need to add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12} in order to use

```
\path[draw=gray, dashed] (10,-2) -- (10,50);
```

otherwise, you may have to use

```
\path[draw=gray, dashed] (axis cs:10,-2) -- (axis cs:10,50);
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[13pt,a4paper,headlines=6,headinclude=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
      \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xmin=-5,xmax=16,ymin=2,ymax=299,
        extra x ticks={0,4,7},
        tick label style={font=\tiny},
        legend style={draw=none,font=\tiny,legend pos=outer north east,cells={anchor=west}}
            ]
            \addplot+[no marks,blue,domain=0.2:10,samples=150, thick] {(x)^3 - 12*(x)^2 + 60*x+98};
        \addlegendentry{$C(x) = x^3 - 12x^2 + 60x+98$};
            \addplot+[no marks,red,domain=0.2:13,samples=150, thick] {3*(x)^2 - 24*x + 60};
            \addlegendentry{$MC(x)=3x^2 - 24x + 60$};
            \addplot+[no marks,orange,domain=0.2:13,samples=150, thick] {(x)^2 - 12*x + 60 + (98)/(x)};
            \addlegendentry{$AV(x)=x^2 - 12x + 60 + \frac{98}{x}$};
            \path[draw=gray, dashed] (4,2) -- (4,50);
            \path[draw=gray, dashed] (10,-2) -- (10,50);
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To change the shape, use `usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}` (for example) and then

```
legend style={ellipse,fill=olive,font=\tiny,legend pos=outer north east,cells={anchor=west}}
```

gives  (ugly)

[image]

With

```
legend style={rounded corners,fill=olive!40,font=\tiny,legend pos=outer north east,cells={anchor=west}}
```

we get

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this perfectly solved my legend problem. I even managed to make this more compact by shifting the legend (e.g. at={(1.2,0.8)},anchor=outer north east).